# Problema com menu flutuante e ID

Tags: css, html5, link, id

Saudações!

Estou fazendo um site e criei algumas sections cada uma com seu respectivo id.
Ocorre que a página possui um menu flutuante que acompanha toda a navegação.
Eu fiz um link no menu para que quando clicarem em um dos itens vá para a id referente na mesma página.
Ocorre que quando clica no menu a section fica desalinhada pois parte do conteúdo está encoberto pelo menu flutuante.
Como eu poderia arrumar esse alinhamento para ficar bem encaixado no site?

Comment: Você poderia criar divs vazias com o tamanho do seu menu antes de cada section, e apontar pra essas divs, assim seu menu ficaria alinhado com a section.

Comment: mas isso não criaria um espaço vazio desnecessário na página fazendo ela perder o layout?

Comment: na vdd não pq elas não tem nd, ou seja sem altura ou tamanho

Comment: Lukas, eu tentei colocar 500 divs e nada de alterar o setfocus automático...

Comment: a solução provisória que encontrei foi aumentar o tamanho do padding mesmo, infelizmente.